# How to solve SQL Exception-Unsupported type JAVA_OBJECT while connecting to Presto with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, presto, spark-shell

I am very new to Apache Spark and trying to connect to Presto from Apache Spark. Below is my Connection String, which giving the error.

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> "jdbc:presto://host:port/hive?user=username&SSL=true&SSLTrustStorePath=/path/certificatefile", "driver" -> "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver", "dbtable" -> "tablename", "fetchSize" ->  "10000", "partitionColumn" -> "columnname", "lowerBound" -> "1988", "upperBound" -> "2016", "numPartitions" -> "28")).load()
```

I have first started start-master.sh within spark/sbin. I also tried setting jar and driver class path in spark-shell like this:

```
./spark-shell  --driver-class-path com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver --jars /path/jar/file
```

Still getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type JAVA_OBJECT
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getCatalystType(JdbcUtils.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$8.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:316)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$8.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:316)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.getSchema(JdbcUtils.scala:315)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
```

Could someone please help me with that? Thanks

Comment: Is your table using any complex types like array or map? Such types in Presto JDBC are exposed as JAVA_OBJECT (List or Map) and it looks like Spark does not support that. In general support for complex types in JDBC specifications is not well defined.

Comment: Why don't you use Spark SQL?

Comment: @Ashish that's what I want to use. Spark SQL. but before that I have to connect to Presto and register temporary view

Comment: You can create temp view in Spark also. Using both Spark and Presto in a single flow may cause some maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There are lines in [Spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fd424caf6c46e7030ac2deb2afbe3f4a5fc1095c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L221)
JDBCUtils.scala

```
case _ =>
  // For unmatched types:
  // including java.sql.Types.ARRAY,DATALINK,DISTINCT,JAVA_OBJECT,NULL,OTHER,REF_CURSOR,
  // TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE,TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE, and among others.
  val jdbcType = classOf[JDBCType].getEnumConstants()
    .find(_.getVendorTypeNumber == sqlType)
    .map(_.getName)
    .getOrElse(sqlType.toString)
  throw QueryExecutionErrors.unrecognizedSqlTypeError(jdbcType, typeName)
```

That's why you receive such an exception.
However, there is a `JdbcDialect` concept, that allows you to create overrides per JDBC-driver.
Simply saying, this snippet should help you to read it as `StringType`.

```
import io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.ClientStandardTypes
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, MetadataBuilder, StringType}

import java.sql.Types
import java.util.Locale

class TrinoJdbcDialect extends JdbcDialect {
  override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = {
    url.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).startsWith("jdbc:trino")
  }

  override def getCatalystType(sqlType: Int, typeName: String, size: Int, md: MetadataBuilder): Option[DataType] = {
    // values are 2000 / "json" as per the moment of writing        
    if (sqlType == Types.JAVA_OBJECT && typeName == ClientStandardTypes.JSON) {
      Some(StringType)
    } else {
      super.getCatalystType(sqlType, typeName, size, md)
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the application startup, you need to add the following line:

```
 JdbcDialects.registerDialect(new TrinoJdbcDialect)
```

Verified that it works as per Spark 3.3 and Trino 420.